# What are examples of $\mathsf{NL}$-complete problems?

Tags: complexity-theory

Wikipedia lists exactly two problems as $\mathsf{NL}$-complete - 2-satisfiability and St-connectivity (although stating that there are "several"):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:NL-complete_problems

My old literature on complexity (from study) also has no additional examples. And the complexity zoo also lists the graph reachability problem as sole example:

https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N

So, are there any other problems known to be $\mathsf{NL}$-complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three more examples, taken from an assignment by [Trevisan](http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs172/ps09.pdf):

1. Given an NFA and a word, determining whether the NFA accepts the word.
2. Reachability in DAGs.
3. Determining whether a digraph is strongly connected.

[Planken](http://www.st.ewi.tudelft.nl/~planken/Papers/literature-survey.pdf) shows that the Simple Temporal Problem with bounded weights is NL-complete (see the link for definitions).

There are likely many others. [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem), in particular, gives many examples.